# Chrome extension with youtube data api can't authenticate/signIn

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to create a chrome extensions using the Youtube data api (in javascript) which manipulates the user's playlists. My code uses a lot of the sample code from the youtube api website. Link to the documentation for adding a video to a playlist: (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert).

The authenticate and the load client functions in the sample code are reused in all the youtube api functions provided, but I don't really understand them. 
I'm getting an error with this line in the authenticate function:

```
.signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"})
```

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of null**

The thing is that I don't even know if the sign in function is really necessary, I'm just using it because it was used in the sample code, I don't want the users to have to re-sign in to google when using the extension.

Here's the offending function:

```
  return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
      .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"})
      .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
            function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
}
```

Here's the whole code for context:

```
  gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "759121533570-dqpfg5rksm7n0j1a2jmi4fv542u1ik1f.apps.googleusercontent.com" });
});

function authenticateList() {
  return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
      .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
      .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
            function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
}

function authenticate() {
  return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
      .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"})
      .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
            function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
}
function loadClient() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(...);
  return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
      .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
          function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
}
// Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
//Lists current playlists
function listPlaylists() {
  return gapi.client.youtube.playlists.list({
    "part": "snippet",
    "maxResults": 50,
    "mine": true
  })
      .then(function(response) {
              // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
              console.log("Response", response);

              let length = response.result.items.length
              for(let i=0; i<length; i++){
                if(response.result.items[i].snippet.title == "Queue"){
                  chrome.storage.sync.set({'playlistId': response.result.items[i].id});
                  return;
                }
              }
              insertQueuePlaylist();
            },
            function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}
//Lists videos in Queue playlist
function listVideos() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
      "part": "snippet",
      "maxResults": 50,
      "playlistId": chrome.storage.sync.get(['playlistId'])
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                return response.result.pageInfo.totalResults;
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }

//Inserts video to playlist
function insertVideo(videoId) {
    return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
      "part": "snippet",
      "resource": {
        "snippet": {
          "playlistId": chrome.storage.sync.get(['playlistId']),
          "position": 0,
          "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": videoId
          }
        }
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}

//Delete video from playlist
function deleteVideo(videoId) {
    return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.delete({
      "id": videoId
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
//Inserts the playlist
function insertQueuePlaylist() {
  return gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert({
    "part": "snippet",
    "resource": {
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Queue",
        "description": "The videos queued to play next"
      }
    }
  })
      .then(function(response) {
              // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
              console.log("Response", response);
              chrome.storage.sync.set({'playlistId': response.result.id});
            },
            function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}


//add queue link
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    authenticate().then(loadClient);
    insertQueuePlaylist();
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      "id": "queueContextMenu",
      "title": "Add to Queue",
      "contexts": ["links"]
    });
  });

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info) {
  if (info.menuItemId == "queueContextMenu") {
      chrome.storage.sync.get(['playlistId'],function(data){
        if(data.playlistId==='undefined'){
          authenticateList().then(loadClient);
          listPlaylists();
        }
      });
      authenticate().then(loadClient);
      let url = new URL(info.linkUrl);
      insertVideo(url.searchParams.get("v"));
    }
})

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(details){
  //before Navigate, get the id of the queue playlist if you don't already have it
  console.log(details.url);
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['playlistId'],function(data){
    if(data.playlistId==='undefined'){
      authenticateList().then(loadClient);
      listPlaylists();
    }
  });
  //get the number of videos in the queue
  let numVideos = listVideos();
  if (numVideos!=0){
    authenticate().then(loadClient);
    //if there are videos in the queue, add the current video to the begining of the queue,
    let url = new URL(details.url);
    let videoId = url.searchParams.get("v");
    insertVideo(vidoId);
    //and enter the playlists
    window.location.search = "?v=" + videoId + "&list=" + chrome.storage.sync.get(['playlistId']);
  }

},{url: [{urlContains : '.youtube.com/watch'}]});

chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details){
  console.log(details.url);

},{url: [{urlContains : '.youtube.com/watch'}]});

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
  authenticate().then(loadClient)
  let url = new URL(details.url);
  let videoId = url.searchParams.get("v");
  deleteVideo(videoId);
},{url: [{queryContains: 'list=' + chrome.storage.sync.get(['playlistId'],function(result) {
          console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
        })}]});
```

I also included "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" at the top of the file. I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I edited out your API key! Please note that the API key is an user's private information. Therefore nobody should include his/her API keys in API url's himself/herself makes public! In such cases, as yours is, that key must be quickly deleted from [Google's developers console](http://console.developers.google.com). Upon that, just ask the Web UI to get you a new key.

Comment: I'm kindly recommending you to read through the [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) -- since you're saying you don't really understand the Javascript code you use. The `.signIn` property is `null` due to unsuccessful authentication. [Here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html) is an thorough example of how things work.